# python - BeautifulSoup - wrap() - add element to multiple sections

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

How to repetetively insert  `<button class="accordion"> </button>`

I have below code where I want to add a button to each header using the wrap function from beautifulsoap library.

I try to loop through h2 objects, find the parent 3 levels up from each header line and insert the button tag. However, the logic doesn't work with the wrap function. One button is placed for two headers and the structure of the code changes.

Can anybody explain the mechanics of the wrap function here / correct the logic used, please?

**Input**

```
<html>
<body>    
    <div class="cell border-box-sizing text_cell rendered">
     <div class="prompt input_prompt">
     </div>
     <div class="inner_cell">
      <div class="text_cell_render border-box-sizing rendered_html">
       <h2 id="Header-1">
        Header 1
        <a class="anchor-link" href="#Header-1">
        </a>
       </h2>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell border-box-sizing text_cell rendered">
     <div class="prompt input_prompt">
     </div>
     <div class="inner_cell">
      <div class="text_cell_render border-box-sizing rendered_html">
       <p TEXT_1
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>  
     <div class="cell border-box-sizing text_cell rendered">
     <div class="prompt input_prompt">
     </div>
     <div class="inner_cell">
      <div class="text_cell_render border-box-sizing rendered_html">
       <h2 id="Header-2">
        Header 2
        <a class="anchor-link" href="#Header-1">
        </a>
       </h2>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(open('snippet_test.html'), 'html.parser')
h2s = soup_2.find_all("h2")
wrapper = soup_2.new_tag('button', **{"class": "accordion"})

for h_2 in h2s:    
     h_2.parent.parent.wrap(wrapper)

html = soup_2.prettify("utf-8")
with open("snippet.html", "wb") as file:
file.write(html)
```

**Output (only one button placed incorrectly, unexpected changes to the code):**

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="cell border-box-sizing text_cell rendered">
   <div class="prompt input_prompt">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell border-box-sizing text_cell rendered">
   <div class="prompt input_prompt">
   </div>
   <div class="inner_cell">
    <div class="text_cell_render border-box-sizing rendered_html">
     <p <="" p="" text_1="">
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell border-box-sizing text_cell rendered">
   <div class="prompt input_prompt">
   </div>
   <button class="accordion">
    <div class="inner_cell">
     <div class="text_cell_render border-box-sizing rendered_html">
      <h2 id="Header-1">
       Header 1
       <a class="anchor-link" href="#Header-1">
       </a>
      </h2>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner_cell">
     <div class="text_cell_render border-box-sizing rendered_html">
      <h2 id="Header-2">
       Header 2
       <a class="anchor-link" href="#Header-1">
       </a>
      </h2>
     </div>
    </div>
   </button>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Desired output:**

```
<html>
<body>
    <button class="accordion" >    
    <div class="cell border-box-sizing text_cell rendered">
     <div class="prompt input_prompt">
     </div>
     <div class="inner_cell">
      <div class="text_cell_render border-box-sizing rendered_html">
       <h2 id="Header-1">
        Header 1
        <a class="anchor-link" href="#Header-1">
        </a>
       </h2>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </button>
    <div class="cell border-box-sizing text_cell rendered">
     <div class="prompt input_prompt">
     </div>
     <div class="inner_cell">
      <div class="text_cell_render border-box-sizing rendered_html">
       <p TEXT_1
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion" >     
     <div class="cell border-box-sizing text_cell rendered">
     <div class="prompt input_prompt">
     </div>
     <div class="inner_cell">
      <div class="text_cell_render border-box-sizing rendered_html">
       <h2 id="Header-2">
        Header 2
        <a class="anchor-link" href="#Header-1">
        </a>
       </h2>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div> 
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only create one wrapper, and you are using it twice. you need to create two objects, one for each header. also i think you want to add one more ".parent"

my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(open('snippet_test.html'), 'html.parser')
h2s = soup_2.find_all("h2")

for h_2 in h2s:
    wrapper = soup_2.new_tag('button', **{"class": "accordion"})
    h_2.parent.parent.parent.wrap(wrapper)

html = soup_2.prettify("utf-8")
with open("snippet.html", "wb") as file:
    file.write(html)
```

Comment: that doesn't work, both headers are under one button either. I want to have a separate button for each header. I have a number of headers in my document so that I try to make a loop to add those buttons.

Comment: are you sure you copied my example exactly? my output has two buttons. I moved the wrapper into the loop, so its creating new tag for each h_2. which versions of python and beautifulsoup you're using? I use python 3.7.0 and beautifulsoup4-4.6.3

Comment: I see, worked! As a next step, I want to add accordion sections by inserting them in a relative position <div class="panelAcc"> below each botton , with the ends before each button. Would you use the wrap function somehow for that either? or is there a better way?

Comment: sorry, i haven't used this library for ages. it sounds like a separate question so should probably be posted separately and I'm sure someone more qualified than me will pick it up. good luck